# How to untar an archive from Pharo Smalltalk?

Tags: tar, smalltalk, pharo

I see there is a GZipReadStream class in Pharo 3.0 for working with gunzip files, but I was unable to find a similar class for untar archives (.tar files).

Do you know if there is a way to untar an archive from Pharo? Maybe without using OSProcess?

Answer (score 1):

A module exists for Visualworks Smalltalk and is available in Cincom public store repository.

http://www.cincomsmalltalk.com/publicRepository/Tar%28Bundle%29.html

I'm not aware of any port for Squeak/Pharo, and it's probably not a straight forward task, but it might be a good source of inspiration.

I didn't see any copyright notice also...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the kernel can decompress tar files. You said no OSProcess - would NativeBoost be cheating? `NBMacShell run: 'tar ...'`. Don't be distracted by "Mac". It uses the standard C library so I don't see why it wouldn't work in Linux/GNU.

Comment: The problem when executing NBMacShell in Linux is "Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console".

Comment: Oh well, so much for that :/